# Advanced order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm working on exporting some records to be put into an excel and sent to customers, the problem is getting the records to come out of the database in the right order.

basically i have a product table with stockcodes (abc13424) and then the product name (hand wash - fragrance, body butter - fragrance etc.).

I have a mix of stockcodes from different years, so abc11234, abc12834, abc13424 etc. what i need to achieve is to essentially display the records grouped by say 'hand wash' from the product name buy then to ultimately have those groups internally and externally sorted by the stockcode.

sample result :-

[image]

Comment: show us sample record with desired result.

Comment: @user1372212 you want to order stockcodes for a product by year? Can you show the sample table as well to get the above results?

Comment: updated with example and no, not by year. but need them grouping into product type based on name and then grouped by code, but also ordering the groups too.

Comment: But this is only your expecte results, not the sample data =)

Comment: What do you mean by "product type"? Is it the part of the name that is before `-`?

Comment: I Will have a look into charindex thanks. the data is quite well structured, just this method of output was never planned for.

Answer (score 2):

It seems what you search for something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `productTable`
ORDER BY `name`, `code`
```

You can list any number of columns in the `ORDER BY` clause. The sorting will then use the first column you mention to sort the resulting data. If you have the same entry in the first column for multiple rows, they will be sorted by the second column given. If those are equal again, the third column will be used etc.

**EDIT**

So according to your comment, it seems, that we need to split one column, in order to make an appropriate ordering.

Assuming, that the `-` character is the delimiter, we can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to split the `name` column like this:

```
SELECT *,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX( `name`, '-', 1) AS `category`
FROM `productTable`
ORDER BY `category`, `code`
```

Comment: this sounds right (like above answer)

Comment: Some questions sound like it needs alot more.. but it's actually a simple asnwer requires.. :)

Comment: this is incorrect, as shown in the above data, the name field will never be the same entry. essentially it is the first few words of the name comment to order by only

Comment: @user1372212 please show us your sample data then..(Sample data that gets the above results)

Comment: the above is not sample data, it is an example of how I would like the output to appear. the sample data are the rows shown above.

Comment: @user1372212 See my edit. Is this, what you wanted to have?

Comment: @sirko this is giving me a similar set of results to just ordering via code.

Comment: @user1372212 Please go to [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) and set up some example data, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @sirko it unfortunately seems to be unavailable at the moment.

Comment: @user1372212 Ok, then just post an excerpt from the (source-)table data in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately it is just example data, the real data cannot be posted, the code format is aaa(yy)111 and the product name is either "type" - "fragrance" or "type-" "fragrance"

Comment: @sirko http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87a0e

Comment: @user1372212 According to [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87a0e/2/0) the above query works.

Comment: Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9037d/1 code abc11411 should be the top of the table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23231/discussion-between-sirko-and-user1372212)